# Enabling antialising in SlimDX (D3D9)

Tags: geometry, antialiasing, slimdx, multisampling

I would like to enable antialiasing when drawing triangles like on the following picture:
[image]

I found a way to do it with XNA on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975403%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) but I want to do the same with *SlimDX*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SlimDX/Directx9, when you create your swapchain, use this in PresentParameters:

```
Multisample = MultisampleType.FourSamples,
MultisampleQuality = 4
```

Also make sure that the multisample state is on (By default it is, but never sure):

```
device.SetRenderState(RenderState.MultisampleAntialias, true);
```

There's of course different type of samples, to find quality/samples, use the following method:

```
new Direct3D().CheckDeviceMultisampleType
```

On dx10+ device, when you create your swapchain, you have a SampleDescription parameter,

so set samples count/quality accordingly

```
SampleDescription samdesc = new SampleDescription(4, 4);
```

To enumerate allowed samplecount/quality combinations:

```
int maxsamplecount = Device.MultisampleCountMaximum
```

Then iterate for sample count using:

```
int maxquality = device.CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(format, sampleCount);
```

It will return 0 if sample count is not supported.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I was struggling with this issue and found an crappy workaround... In addition its my birthday today so again a big thank you! enjoy your bounty reward ;)

Comment: Thanks and hope you had nice birthday )

Comment: Hi carflier, this doesn't work with the present parameter "windowed" set to false, do you have an idea?

Comment: I created a specific question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899885/multisampling-doesnt-work-in-exclusive-mode?lq=1

Comment: @tinmaru Saw it I'll have a look pretty soon

Comment: great! I open the bounty in ... 48 minutes :)