# Multisampling doesn't work in exclusive mode

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx, multisampling

I would like to enable multisampling when drawing triangles like on the following picture:
[image]

I found a way to do with *SlimDX* in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351424/enabling-antialising-in-slimdx-d3d9) but it doesn't work in exclusive mode.

Here is my code:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Direct3D d3d = new Direct3D();

    PresentParameters presentParams;

    presentParams.Windowed = false;
    presentParams.BackBufferFormat = Format.X8R8G8B8;
    presentParams.BackBufferWidth = 800;
    presentParams.BackBufferHeight = 600;
    presentParams.FullScreenRefreshRateInHertz = 60;
    presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Copy;
    presentParams.BackBufferCount = 1;
    presentParams.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One;

    int multisampleQuality;
    Result result;
    if (d3d.CheckDeviceMultisampleType(adaptor, DeviceType.Hardware, Format.X8R8G8B8, false, MultisampleType.FourSamples, out multisampleQuality, out result))
    {
        if(multisampleQuality > 4)
        {
            presentParams.Multisample = multisampleType;
            presentParams.MultisampleQuality = 4;
        }
    }

    // Device creation
    Device device = new Device(d3d, adaptor, DeviceType.Hardware, this.Handle, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);
}
```

The last line alway crashs with a *D3DERR_INVALIDCALL* error even if the *CheckDeviceMultisampleType* return always true with no error and 8 for *multisampleQuality*.

It works if I use the windowed mode or if I remove the multisample option.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
 presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
```

Comment: Hi @catflier! Do you have an explanation for that? I realized that in fact I do need this present parameter to be set to *SwapEffect.Copy*...

Comment: @tinmaru : Yes there's some reasons why you can't do that, mostly since swapeffect.copy needs to copy pixel per pixel, so it would not work with msaa (since you have sub pixel samples). Also why would you need SwapEffect.Copy? Discard is pretty mush the standard